# EntityManager.refresh detached entity throws exception why in your opinion?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I understand that the `JPA` specifications mandates that if a detached entity is passed to the `entityManager.refresh()` then an `IllegalArgumentException` shall be thrown, but I don't understand why? The meaning of the refresh method is ignore any changes done and give 
me a fresh new copy from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the purpose of this lies in actual usage of `refresh` method.

You need to use refresh when between read and actual usage of entity some changes in db could occur. For example, before using some field you want to minimize obsoleteness of data. You call `refresh`. EM pulls up-to-date changes from DB.

If you would pass over detached entity the purpose of using `refresh` becomes somehow needless. Why is it not easier to look up fresh entity by using `find`?

Comment: Yes I am inline with you, I need to get up-to-date changes from DB so what is the problem with passing a detached entity? just bring me the latest version from the DB of this entity why should I merge it?

Answer (score 0):

If your JPA 2.0 implementation is EclipseLink then according to [this documentation](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_persistence_context_flushmode.htm), you don't need to worry about refreshing your entity manager. By default it is being refreshed for you at every query execution.

#### Edit

You are right I did not understand your question first. To answer your question please refer to the JSR-317 JPA specifications from which I quote:

> Detached entity instances continue to live outside of the persistence context in which they were persisted or retrieved. Their state is no longer guaranteed to be synchronized with the database state.

In my words, a detached entity is not visible to the entity manager, thus, it makes sense that the entity manager when passed a detached entity it sees it as "Illegal argument"

To confirm my argument, please check out [this illustration](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/img/jpa-state-transitions.png) which summarizes the JPA entity lifecycle. It clearly shows that the refresh() method is only applicable to the MANAGED entity state only.

[image: JPA entity lifecycle]

#### I expect your next question to be:

*When does a MANAGED entity **need** to be refreshed/synchronized with the database*?

Here comes my first answer to play.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: I know that to refresh an entity it must be managed, and this is what I am saying in my question (I understand that the JPA specification...) my question is why the specification is demanding this requirement! since the "refresh" method is used to reload an entity and discard updates, the EntityManager don't need to guarantee the state of such entity being refreshed it is asked to give me back a refreshed entity from the DB and discard any changes.

Comment: Be definition, the refresh() method can not convert a detached entity into a managed one.